# SharePoint 2013 User Profile SYNC Mysite does export data to AD?

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have been try export data of Mysite to Active Directory. In the manage user properties i have configured the mapping to export direction, but after the full sync dont update in my Active Directory.

Any one can help me?

tks.

Comment: are you using the UPA Sync or ADI or MIM?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of steps to [configuring Write back to AD](http://guides.wmlcloud.com/technology/sharepoint-2013---configuring-user-profile-synchronization-(part-4)---writing-back-to-active-directory.aspx).  I would copy the text of the article here but it copied very poorly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you first configure the UPSA? If so, please check the below things:

1. The Farm Account must be added to local administrator group during starting UPS service.
2. Farm Account must have Log on Locally rights.

Please go to User Profile Service Application > Configure Synchronization Settings, make sure you are using SharePoint Profile Synchronization for Synchronization options. Also make sure your profile properties are mapped correctly. Here is a link about how to export data to active directory:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/administration/configure-profile-synchronization#phase-4-configure-connections-and-export-data-to-directory-services

In addition, you can use miisclient to get more error message. Below is the default location of the miisclient:

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\Synchronization Service\UIShell\miisclient.exe